# Controlling the individual pixels of a projector

Tags: c++, c, image, r, opengl

I need to control the individual pixels of a projector (an Infocus IN3104) whose native resolution is 1024x768.  I would like to know which **subset** of functions in C or an APL to do this either by:

1. Functions that control the individual pixels of the adapter (not the pixels of a window).
2. A pixel-perfect, 1:1 map from an image file (1024x728) to the adaptor set at the native resolution of the projector.

In a related question ([How can I edit individual pixels in a window?][1]) the answerer  Caladain states "Things have come a bit from the old days of direct memory manipulation.".  I feel I need to go back to that to achieve my goal.

I don't know enough of the "graphic pipeline" to know what API or software tool to use.  I'm overwhelmed by the number of technologies when I search this topic.  I program in R, which easily interfaces to C, but would welcome suggestions of **subsets** of functions in OpenGL or C++ or ..... any other technology?

Or even an full blown application (rendering) which will map without applying a transformation.

For example even MS paint has the >VIEW>Bitmap but I get some transformation applied and I don't get pixel perfect rendering.  This projector has DisplayLink digital input and I've also tried to tweek the timing parameters when using the VESA inputs and I don't think the transformation happens in the projector.  In any case, using MS paint would not be flexible enough for me.

Platform:  Linux or Windows.

Comment: The two platforms (Linux and Windows) are so vastly different in terms of their windowing and drawing systems that you'll have to pick one before folks can really assist you further.

Comment: Thank you.  I have both machines running and welcome suggestions in either Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach to this problem on current systems is:

1. Set graphics card to desired resolution
2. Create borderless full screen window
3. Draw whatever you want

There's really not much to gain from a "low level access", although it were certainly possible.

Comment: datenwolf: What tools/functions/APL would you use to 'Create borderless full screen window'?  I'm that ignorant of the whole graphics layers.  Would you know the function names in say, Cairo, to do this ?

Comment: Cairo is a vector graphics library, it doesn't deal with Windowing. The right place to look for are GUI toolkits like GTK or Qt. Or the already mentioned SDL which offers a fullscreen mode and setting the display resolution. Setting the resolution is important to get 1:1 mapping from screen pixels to display device pixels.

Comment: I have selected your answer for mentioning GTK.  I selected this toolkit because it had binding in R. (For those who care, the package is [RGtk2](http://probability.ca/cran/web/packages/RGtk2/index.html) )  It took me a while to install all the required libraries and finally installing the package, but I was successful.  It somewhat "bleeds" a little but I get fairly good 1:1.  The bleeding could be due to lens distortion.  Thanks again for your help a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: @Andre: The bleeding could be a effect a lot of people trip over: Textures are actually treated as sampling points for interpolation over the range [0,1], where this range is divided into N×M subintervals, where the texture's pixels define the mean value of each subinterval. So when addressing texture coordinated {0, 1} then you don't hit the texel centers. With an apropriate projection, i.e. glOrtho(0,1,0,1,-1,1) this cancels out, but say glOrtho(0,texWidth,0,texHeight,-1,1) things won't work out anymore; I think you can figure it out yourself - if not, I answered this a couple of times.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see a reason why a full-screen window, e.g. using [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), wouldn't work. Normal bitmapped graphics is always 1:1, there shouldn't be any weird scaling going on behind your back for a full-screen:ed window.

Since SDL is portable, you should be able to run the same code in Windows or Linux (or any other supported platform).

Comment: The "low level access" mentioned sounds promising.  I will study this.

Comment: @Andre Where do you see "low level access" in this answer?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Not in the answer.  In the link to the APL suggested http://www.libsdl.org/

Comment: @Andre: There's nothing low level with SDL